# Yocto fetcher failure for libnotify

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, libnotify

I'm trying to build a Yocto receipe that depends on libnotify. When it attempts to build libnotify I get a fetcher error: "ERROR: libnotify-0.7.8-r0 do_fetch: Bitbake Fetcher Error: FetchError('Unable to fetch URL from any source.', 'https://download.gnome.org/sources//libnotify/0.7/libnotify-0.7.8.tar.xz;name=archive')" I noticed that the URL has an extra / in it. I tried looking in /meta/recipes-gnome/libnotify/libnotify_0.7.8.bb but I don't see a SRC_URI defined so I don't understand where it is getting this URI from. Does someone know how to correct this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An SRC_URI pointing to this URL: `https://download.gnome.org/sources//libnotify/0.7/libnotify-0.7.8.tar.xz` must exist.

In `/meta/recipes-gnome/libnotify/libnotify_0.7.8.bb` there is an `SRC_URI[archive.md5sum] =babb...` Here "archive" is the name of the SRC_URI which is defined elsewhere more likely in **classes/clutter.bbclass** or **classes/gnomebase.bbclass**

Make sure you have not a proxy then try to build again.
As a workaround. You can download this archive with wget command.

```
wget https://download.gnome.org/sources//libnotify/0.7/libnotify-0.7.8.tar.xz;name=archive
```

Put it inside your download directory.
Then create inside the download directory a file named as the archive but with .done extension at the end.

```
touch libnotify-0.7.8.tar.xz.done
```

Thus, bitbake will notice that the archive is already present and there is no need to fetch it again.

Comment: I used your workaround method. For some reason wget couldn't resolve the URL either and I'm pretty sure I don't have a proxy. I downloaded the archive using my web browser and created the .done file as you suggested and that worked.